# return this.name и отличие

Tags: java

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    private void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Увидел вот такой пример и увидел: `return this.name`, вопрос: Чем отличается return this.name от return name в данном примере? Почему так написано  `return this.name;`?

Comment: Это банальное обращение к свойству `name`, через контекст `this`, что можно и не писать, но рекомендуется именно писать, чтобы было читабельно и понятно откуда происходит вызов с текущего объекта, а не в противном случае `super` с родителя. Хотя иногда поля могут перекрывать друг-друга, тут то и поможет `super., this., Class.`

Comment: @And не очень понимаю почему еще в примере приватный сеттер

Comment: Это уже отдельный вопрос, вы об этом не сказали, приватный, чтобы работать только в данном объекте / классе. Прочитайте про модификаторы доступа, есть еще и `protected` или вовсе отсутствие модификатора, что будет работать только в текущем пакете в котором определен класс..

Comment: @And просто я тестирую с return this.name и this.name идентичный результат в консоле, тогда почему бы не писать просто return name если это грубо говоря экономит время хоть и секунды

Comment: Повторяю, может перекрывать поля, если будут определены к примеру `String name`; в методе, то вы не сможете вернуть свойство объекта, а вот если `this.name` сможете. А вообще, лучше всегда писать `this, super, Class` для читабельности и понятного происхождения того или иного свойства.

Comment: `this` следовательно спецификации нужно использовать только в конструкторе, если название аргумента конструктора совпадает с названием поля. каких-то других причин, где использовать `this` в джаве конкретных нету.

Comment: @raviga то есть в геттере я должен был написать return name и всё? Я правильно понял? Можно еще ссыль пожалуйста на источник

Comment: @MikeMclaren. да. как источник вы можете взять материал по которому готовятся к сертификации `Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 8 Programmer`. Там есть целый раздел, который описывает как правильно использовать `this` и по словам самих разработчиком `Java`, указывать в геттер `this` не имеет абсолютно никакого плюса или минуса. Это просто лишнее слово в геттере.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` в выражении `return this.name;` явным образом указывает что поле `name`  считывается из текущего экземпляра объекта `Student`, а не откуда-то еще, например из аргумента функции.

Сравните эти 2 примера:

```
public class Student1 {

    private String name;

    public String setAndReturnName(String name){
       this.name = name + name;
       return this.name;
    }
 }
```

---

```
public class Student2 {

    private String name;

    public String setAndReturnName(String name){
       this.name = name + name;
       return name;
    }
 }
```

---

```
System.out.println(new Student1().setAndReturnName("abc")); // abcabc
System.out.println(new Student2().setAndReturnName("abc")); // abc
```

Answer (score 9):

В данном случае для метода `getName()` нет никакой разницы, потому что возвращается именно тот `name` который в классе является единственным. А вот для примера `setName(String name)` разница есть. Здесь `this.name` указывает именно на переменную класса, а просто `name` это та переменная, которую передали в метод `setName`.

Данный класс, можно переписать вот так

```
public class Human{
    int age;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;   
    }
    public void setAge(int newAge){
        age=newAge;   
    }
}

public class Student extends Human{

    private String name;


    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
        super.setAge(10);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;    
// Здесь убрали параметр this, т.к. нет других name, которые нужно возвращать
    }

    public void setName(String name1){
        name = name1;    
// Здесь можно оставить как у вас в примере или переписать так как у меня.
// Ключевое слово this ссылается на текущий класс, аналогично как super ссылается на класс, который является родителем текущего класса
    }
}
```

К тому же, в вашем примере, метод setName не может быть private, в противном случае, он будет работать только в рамках вашего класса Student и всё

Comment: Не очень понял, вы можете на примере показать пожалуйста?

Comment: @MikeMclaren, добавил. Может быть стало понятнее?

Comment: у вас return отсутствует в классе Human в сеттере

Comment: @MikeMclaren в сэттерах не должно быть return, обычно. Потому что они только устанавливают значение и ничего не возвращают.

Comment: Я знаю, извините написал у себя public int ,а не void и думал что это геттер

Comment: Не страшно) Все мы учимся

Comment: как я понял по сути return this.name это тоже самое что и return name если мы используем в геттере потому что в сетере мы напишем this.name = name и тогда получается в геттере незачем писать return this.name и можем просто написать return name Да?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92827/discussion-between-dred-and-mike-mclaren).

Comment: я уже по примеру выше понял как работает, спасибо за помощь вам тоже!